# How to pop entire item from array?

Tags: python

I want to randomly assign the three items from list into randlist but I also don't want the items to be assigned more than once

I tried to use a while loop that would pop the items randomly into randlist but it seems to be taking characters from the array item instead of the entire string.

```
from random import randint

list = ["car", "zonk1", "zonk2"]
randlist = []
x = 0

while x < 3:
    randlist += list.pop(randint(0, len(list) - 1))
    x += 1

door1 = randlist[0]
door2 = randlist[1]
door3 = randlist[2]

print (door1, door2, door3)
```

Result:

```
z o n
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: You could just copy the list and shuffle it. Or use `random.sample` with N.

Comment: Use permutations instead

Comment: Why not use `randlist.append(list.pop(randint(0, len(list) - 1)))`?

Comment: use `append ` instead of `+=` while assignment in the new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
randlist += list.pop(randint(0, len(list) - 1))
```

*extends* the `str` object, character by character, into the list.

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist += 'foo'
>>> mylist
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

You want to *append* what you are popping.

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> mylist.append('foo')
>>> mylist
['foo']
```

---

As an aside, you should use other functions in the `random` module instead of re-inventing the wheel. You want a *random sample* from your list:

```
>>> import random
>>> mylist = ["car", "zonk1", "zonk2"]
>>> random.sample(mylist, 3)
['zonk1', 'car', 'zonk2']
>>> random.sample(mylist, 3)
['zonk2', 'car', 'zonk1']
>>> random.sample(mylist, 3)
['car', 'zonk2', 'zonk1']
```

Comment: This does not at all address the problem of duplication.

Comment: @BlueRineS well, although I would not recommend the OPs approach, I think it does avoid the problem of duplication.

Comment: No it will not. OP states he does not want duplicates from list into mylist, which is wat can happen when using randint!

Comment: @BlueRineS no, because the argument to `randint` will change on each iteration of the loop, as the `len` of the source lists decreases, and `.pop` is a destructive operation, i.e. it operates in place, so you cannot draw the same item more than once.

Comment: You are totally right. I did not consider the effect of pop() for a second. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use numpy. Then the following code is slightly faster (and arguably neater) than for-looping:

```
import numpy as np

_list = ["car", "zonk1", "zonk2"]
idx = np.random.permutation(len(_list))
mylist = list(np.array(_list)[idx])
```

Example output:

```
>>> mylist
['zonk1', 'car', 'zonk2']
```

Comment: I've added an update to my answer (not necessarily better than yours @juanpa.arrivillaga , but adds some extra flavor to choose from for the OP.